# C++ operator overloading in abstract class

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, operator-keyword, abstract

Let's say we have the following scenario:

We have a base abstract class `A`. Then we have classes `B` and `C` which derived from `A`. We also have class `D` which is a custom implementation of a `std::vector<T>` - it contains a private property `list` of type `std::vector<T>` and some custom methods to work with it.

Now my problem is as follows: I would like to overload the `operator +` in class `A` to be able to do this:

```
    B* b = new B(); 
    C* c = new C(); 
    D mList = b+c; //the property *list* of mList would contain b an c
```

I have tried everything and can't seem to be able to get it to work and am out of ideas. Is it even possible to override an operator in a base abstract class so that it will apply to derived classes?

EDIT:

Here is what I have tried so far:

File A.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{

protected:
double price;
string name;
    public:
    A() :name(""){};
    A(string n, double p){
    price = p;
    name = n;
};
~A(){};
virtual void calculate(double value) = 0;
virtual void print() const = 0;
};
```

File B.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "A.h"

class B : public A
{
private:
public:
    B() :A(){};
    B(string n, double p) :A(n,p){};
    ~B();

    void calculate(double value)
    {
    price = price + value;
    }

    void print() const
    {
        cout << name << " says: " << " " << price;
    }
};
```

File C.h:

```
#include "A.h"

class C : public A
{
private:
public:
    C() :A(){};
    C(string n, double p) : A(n,p){};
    ~C();

    void calculate(double value)
    {
    price = price * value;
   }

void print() const
{
    cout << name << " says: " << " " << price;
}
```

};

File D.H:

```
#include <vector>
class D
{
private:
    vector<A*> list;
public:
    D(){}
    ~D()
    {
        int len = list.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            delete list[i];
        }
    };
    void push(A* item)
    {
        list.push_back(item);
     }
    A* pop()
    {
        A* last = list.back();
        list.pop_back();
        return last;
    }

        //I have tried overriding it here and in A.h
    friend D D::operator+(A* first, A* second)
    {
        D temp;
        temp.push(first);
        temp.push(second);
        return temp;
    }
};
```

Comment: Show us an example of the whole thing, including the base class A and the operator overloading attempt!

Comment: [learn how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  [Post a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `operator+` does not perform the natural operation it is supposed to do. Now what is your question? what is the error here?

Comment: Adding `b` and `c` doesn't make sense, as they are pointers. You probably didn't mean to use `new` in the first place.

Comment: Every occurrence of `{};` should be replaced by `{}`. Just for appearances' sake.

Comment: operators are not for polymorphism. you are just using it in wrong way

Answer (score 0):

Here's an compilable and runnable example (http://codepad.org/cQU2VHMp) I wrote before you clarified the question, maybe it helps. The idea is that the addition overload can either be unary (and D defined as a friend), as here, or defined as a non-member binary operator using public methods. Note that I have to dereference the pointers b and c to make this work, as adding pointers often don't make sense.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class D {
public:
    void Foo() {
        std::cout << "D: " << member_ << std::endl;
    }
    friend class A;
private:
    std::string member_;
};

class A {
public:
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
    A(const std::string &member) : member_(member) {}
    D operator+(const A &rhs) {
        D out;
        out.member_ = member_ + " " + rhs.member_;
        return out; // Uses the default copy constructor of D
    }
protected:
    std::string member_;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(const std::string &member) : A(member) {}
    void Foo() { 
        std::cout << "B: " << member_ << std::endl;
    }
};

class C : public A {
public:
    C(const std::string &member) : A(member) {}
    void Foo() { 
        std::cout << "C: " << member_ << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    B *b = new B("hello");
    C *c = new C("world");
    b->Foo();
    c->Foo();
    D d = (*b) + (*c);
    d.Foo();
    delete b;
    delete c;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
B: hello
C: world
D: hello world
```

Comment: I'm getting a few errors here in class A: 'D' undeclared identifier and 'missing type specifier'.

Comment: @DavidFenko Here's a codepad with the whole thing: http://codepad.org/cQU2VHMp. Compiles nicely in VS too, but I might have forgot some detail in this quick example.

Comment: Here is what I'm trying to accomplish and the errors I get: http://codepad.org/DUZKRKHB

Comment: Your problems are related to the order in which classes are defined. Note that to return a D, the D class must be defined. Also, in order to call delete on an A pointer, A needs to be defined. You'll have to rethink your design and dependencies a little.

Comment: For example, this compiles http://codepad.org/IRrBNGQp by removing the call to delete, and by moving class D to the top and forward declaring A above that. What you'll have to to is make sure the allocated A objects get deleted elsewhere. Since they are created outside of the D class (passed in as pointers), maybe that's a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When `c in C*` and `d is a D*` if you write `c+d` **you're just adding pointers**, whatever overloads you defined.

Maybe you could redefine pointer addition for `A*` with a global `operator(A*, A*)` (not sure it's possible) but it would be quite dangerous for users since it overrides standard behavior.

The better **solution is to define operators on references** (const) and not pointers, which in your case is a little less convenient since you'd have to write: `list = *c + *d;`

Also, since you're using containers of pointers for polymorphism, I strongly recommend using `shared_ptr`.

Working code below (simplified, but with the ability to add more than 2 elements):

```
#include <list>
using std::list;

struct A {
    list<const A*> operator+(const A& right) { // A + A
        list<const A*> r;
        r.push_back(this);
        r.push_back(&right);
        return r;
    }
    list<const A*> operator+(const list<const A*> & right) { // A + list
        list<const A*> r = right;
        r.push_front(this);
        return r;
    }
    virtual void print() const = 0;
};

list<const A*> operator+(const list<const A*> & left, const A & right) { // list + A
    list<const A*> r = left;
    r.push_back(&right);
    return r;
}


#include <iostream>
struct B : A {
    void print() const { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
};
struct C : A {
    void print() const { std::cout << "C" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    C c;
    B* pb = new B;
    list<const A*> lst = b + c + *pb;

    for(list<const A*>::iterator i = lst.begin(); i != lst.end(); ++i) {
        (*i)->print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're are adding two pointers, so A::operator+() won't even be called. But to answer your question, yes, operator overloading is inheritable. Even from an abstract base class.

```
class A
{
    public:
        virtual void test() = 0;
        int operator+(const A &a) {return 42;}
};

class B : public A
{
    void test() {};
};

class C : public A
{
    void test() {};
};

int main()
{
    B* b = new B();
    C* c = new C();

    cout << "result: " << *b + *c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
result: 42
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code-example:

```
#include <iostream>

class B;
class A;

class A
{
public:
    virtual void overrideProp() = 0;

    friend int operator+(const B& b, const A& a);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& a)
    {
        return os << a.prop;
    }

protected:
    int prop;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(){overrideProp();}
    void overrideProp(){prop=1;}
};

class C : public A
{
public:
    C(){overrideProp();}
    void overrideProp(){prop=3;}    
};

int operator+(const B& b, const A& a)
{
    return b.prop + a.prop;      
}


class D
{
public:

    void operator=(const int& i){d = i;}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const D& a)
    {
        return os << a.d;
    }

private:
    int d;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    C c;
    D d; d = b+c;

    std::cout << "B contains: " << b << " C contains: " << c << " D contains: " << d;
}
```

The output is `B contains: 1 C contains: 3 D contains: 4`